# Swedish 'Personnummer' validator

Tags: c#, algorithm, regex, validation, checksum

I have a small C# program that validates Swedish social security numbers (['Personnummer'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_%28Sweden%29)).

I chose to use Regex as there are many different ways it can be input.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Personnummer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class used to verify Swedish social security numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Personnummer
    {
        private static readonly Regex regex;
        private static readonly CultureInfo cultureInfo;

        static Personnummer()
        {
            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
            regex       = new Regex(@"(\d{2}){0,1}(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})([-|+]{0,1})?(\d{3})(\d{0,1})");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the checksum value of a given digit-sequence as string by using the luhn/mod10 algorithm.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Sequense of digits as a string.</param>
        /// <returns>Resulting checksum value.</returns>
        private static int Luhn(string value)
        {
            // Luhm algorithm doubles every other number in the value.
            // To get the correct checksum digit we aught to append a 0 on the sequence.
            // If the result becomes a two digit number, subtract 9 from the value.
            // If the total sum is not a 0, the last checksum value should be subtracted from 10.
            // The resulting value is the check value that we use as control number.

            // The value passed is a string, so we aught to get the actual integer value from each char (i.e., subtract '0' which is 48).
            int[] t = value.ToCharArray().Select(d => d - 48).ToArray();
            int sum = 0;
            int temp;
            for (int i = t.Length; i -->0; )
            {
                temp = t[i];
                sum += (i % 2 == t.Length % 2) 
                    ? ((temp * 2) % 10) + temp / 5 
                    : temp;
            }

            return sum % 10;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Function to make sure that the passed year, month and day is parseable to a date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="year">Years as string.</param>
        /// <param name="month">Month as int.</param>
        /// <param name="day">Day as int.</param>
        /// <returns>Result.</returns>
        private static bool TestDate(string year, int month, int day)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dt = new DateTime(cultureInfo.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(int.Parse(year)), month, day);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validate Swedish social security number.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value as string.</param>
        /// <returns>Result.</returns>
        public static bool Valid(string value)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(value);

            if (matches.Count < 1 || matches[0].Groups.Count < 7)
            {
                return false;
            }

            GroupCollection groups = matches[0].Groups;
            int month, day, check;
            string yStr;
            try
            {
                yStr  = (groups[2].Value.Length == 4) ? groups[2].Value.Substring(2) : groups[2].Value;
                month = int.Parse(groups[3].Value);
                day   = int.Parse(groups[4].Value);
                check = int.Parse(groups[7].Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Could not parse. So invalid.
                return false;
            }

            bool valid = Luhn($"{yStr}{groups[3].Value}{groups[4].Value}{groups[6].Value}{check}") == 0;
            return valid && (TestDate(yStr, month, day) || TestDate(yStr, month, day - 60));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validate Swedish social security number.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value as long.</param>
        /// <returns>Result.</returns>
        public static bool Valid(long value)
        {
            return Valid(value.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I need this Luhn validator but I’m new to this. I have a webform that gets data from sql and then I need to validate the personnummer. How can I call the class or static Luhn from a button click?

Comment: Add the whole namespace to your codebase, then, when you want to validate it just call Personnummer.Valid(your_input_text_here). It should work.  You can add me on discord joanjetta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `@"(\d{2}){0,1}(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})([-|+]{0,1})?(\d{3})(\d{0,1})"`

You `Regex` pattern should check for start and end anchors by placing an `'^'` at start and `'$'` at the end:

`@"^(\d{2}){0,1}(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})([-|+]{0,1})?(\d{3})(\d{0,1})$"`

If you don't do that, the following "number" is valid:

```
"xx811228-9874yyyy"
```

---

You can name the  groups in a `Regex` pattern:

```
string pattern = @"^(?<year>(\d{2}){1,2})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})[-|+]{1}(?<litra>\d{3})(?<check>\d{1})$";
```

This will make it more readable and maintainable and you can access each part by name:

```
int year = int.Parse(match.Groups["year"].Value)
```

---

> `yStr = (groups[2].Value.Length == 4) ? groups[2].Value.Substring(2) : groups[2].Value;`

Instead you could do

```
      int year = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) % 100;
```

where the `% 100` will remove the century part.

---

> `int[] t = value.ToCharArray().Select(d => d - 48).ToArray();`

In general `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` so there's no need for `.ToCharArray()`

It's safe to write:

```
int[] t = value.Select(d => d - '0').ToArray();
```

---

> ```
>   bool valid = Luhn($"{yStr}{groups[3].Value}{groups[4].Value}{groups[6].Value}{check}") == 0;
>   return valid && (TestDate(yStr, month, day) || TestDate(yStr, month, day - 60));
> ```

I think I'd check the date before calling `Luhn()` as the Luhn result makes no sense with an invalid date, and you could avoid one of the calls to `TestDate` if you validate the `day` value against 60:

```
if (day > 60) 
{
  day -= 60;
}
```

---

> `for (int i = t.Length; i-- > 0;)`

This is a rather unusual way to use a for-loop and difficult to understand, because you have to think about when `i` is actually decremented. Is there any reason to iterate backwards?

Why not just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++) {...}
```

---

IMO the `Valid()` method (which should maybe be called `Validate(string number)`) is doing too much. Split it up in appropriate dedicated methods like:

```
public static bool Validate(string number)
{
  try
  {
    var parts = Split(number);
    CheckDate(parts);
    CheckLuhn(parts);
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Here `parts` could be a named tuple:

```
(int year, int month, int day, int litra, int check) parts
```

or you could create a dedicated `class/struct` for that.

`CheckDate()` and `CheckLuhn()` don't return `bool` but throws if an error is detected.

You could consider to let `Validate()` throw as well instead of returning `bool` on error in order to be able to inform the client of the kind of error and/or where it happened.